# Deleted Default png now Build Failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've just finished my project and I was trying to add the correct Default images to it.

I got a build error with pngcrush so I deleted the Default images and tried re-adding them...

Now I get build failed and this error...

```
CopyPNGFile "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-focehhxhholrseatdpjqdglseomk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appName.app/Default@2x.png" "i-snapshot/Default@2x.png"
    cd /Users/me/Documents/appName
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng -compress "" "/Users/me/Documents/appName/appName/Default@2x.png" "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName-focehhxhholrseatdpjqdglseomk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appName.app/Default@2x.png"

Can't find /Users/me/Documents/appName/appName/Default@2x.pngCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried:

- Adding the files back in.
- Adding then deleting again.
- Deleting derived data.
- Clean and build.

now I'm stuck, no idea what to do and the app just won't build at all.

Comment: OMG, panic over. I just saw the "Can't find..." message whilst posting this question. I added the files back into that folder (no idea why) and now it works :D "Phew" does not fully convey what I am feeling right now.

Comment: Did you do a full clean of your build folder? It's the 'clean' command in the menu with a modifier key - hold done the.. option or command key - I forget, to do a full clean.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that. I will try it next time though. Just did a full clean now and it seems to be working again. Thanks :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delete the png to "Copy Bundle Ressources" :

[image: Delete the png to Copy Bundle Ressources]

Comment: Thanks, will definitely remember this next time.

Answer (score 3):

Goto project target ->Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

and search for your image file name

and remove duplicate image file name